# RegEx: замена символов между скобок в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть строка:

```
$s = 'lorem ~ ips~um <dolor ~ sit> amet, <~ consectetur ~ adipiscing> elit~';
```

Пытаюсь написать регулярку (PCRE), которая заменяла бы тильды только (!) между скобок.
Для удобства написания прототипа регулярки я использовал вместо нормальных скобок "<" и ">".

То есть, результат должен быть таким:

```
$s = 'lorem ~ ips~um <dolor ~ sit> amet, <~ consectetur ~ adipiscing> elit~';
$s = preg_replace('/.../', '@', $s);

// $s = 'lorem ~ ips~um <dolor @ sit> amet, <@ consectetur @ adipiscing> elit~';
```

Уточнения:

- скобки парные;
- в исходной строке вложенных скобок быть не может;
- все скобки открыты/закрыты в нормальном порядке;
- незакрытых скобок нет.

Эти погрешности в регулярке учитывать не надо, но я все-равно запутался и не могу решить задачу.

У меня получилось заменять только одну тильду между скобок:

```
// $s = 'lorem ~ ips~um <dolor @ sit> amet, <~ consectetur ~ adipiscing> elit~';
```

Временно решу проблему другим способом: разобью строку на массив по маске /[<>]/ и произведу замену тильд в нечетных элементах, но это не тру :)

Все-равно задачка (и аналогичные ей) давно уже меня смущает, прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('/<[^>]+>/', function($m) {
    return str_replace('~', '@', $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это лучше, конечно, чем мой велик с массивом. Но тут уже дело принципа – понять, где я лажаю и чего не знаю. То есть, я хочу понять, каким образом можно скомандовать обработчику регулярки: «пойми, что скобка открыта», «в этом блоке запоминай только символы [^~]*», «скобка закрыта, не запоминай, пока не увидишь следующую открывающую скобку».
На stackoverflow я наткнулся на какую-то регулярку (по довольно близкой теме). В ней нечто вроде подстрок и условий были заключены в фигурные скобки. Я привык, что {} – это условие длины. Но там другое: "{\<a *href\=\"[^\"]*" *rel\=\"}{([^ ]*|....

Answer (score 0):

Выполнять следует в несколько шагов, а не одним выражением.

```
$array; 
$search_string = 'lorem ~ ips~um <dolor ~ sit> amet, <~ consectetur ~ adipiscing> elit~';

        // Шаги
        // 1) получить все скобки в массив
        preg_match_all('/(?<=[<]).+?(?=[>])/',$search_string, $array);

        // сохраняем оригинал поиска
        $saved_array = $array[0];
        $array = $array[0];

        // 2) Заменить в массиве все тильды
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($array)-1; $i++)
        {
        $array[$i] = preg_replace('[~]','@', $array[$i]); 
        }

        // 3) В исходной строке заменяем все значения на новые. Выполняя поиск по сохраненному массиву,
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($saved_array)-1; $i++)
        {
        $search_string = str_replace ( $saved_array[$i] , $array[$i] , $search_string );
        }

        echo '<br>Готовая строка: ' . $search_string;
```